# Basic Main Menu code not working

Tags: c, function, menu, structure, program-entry-point

So what I am trying to do is write a simple program with a main menu where the user will be able to fill in the details of a project,list all projects, delete a chosen project or exit the program. Projects will be saved in an array. The functions will use structures.

I have written a functional code which compiles fine(big deal lol i know) but thus far only the 4th option "exit" works. The other 3 choices seem to not be working.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct fullname
{
        char name[10];
        char surname[10];
};
struct meletes
{
        int identifier;
        struct fullname customer;
        char date[10];
        float price;
};
void initialize(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes newp(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes list(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes deletep(struct meletes projects[10]);

int main(void)
{
int choice,k;
struct meletes projects[10];

void initialize(struct meletes projects[10]);

printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
scanf("%d", &choice);

    while ((choice != 1) && (choice != 2) && (choice != 3) && (choice != 4))
          {

           printf("You have chosen a wrong function, please use numbers 1-4:\n\n");
           printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
           printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
           printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
           scanf("%d", &choice);
           }

          while (choice != 4)
          {
          switch (choice) {

                 case 1:
                 {
                  struct meletes newp(struct meletes projects[10]);

                  }

                 case 2:
                 {
                  struct meletes deletep(struct meletes projects[10]);

                  }

                 case 3:
                 {
                  struct meletes list(struct meletes projects[10]);

                  }
                         }


            printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
            printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
            printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
            scanf("%d", &choice);             

          }        

          printf("Thank u.\n");

system("pause");
return 0;
}

 void initialize(struct meletes projects[10])
 {
int l;
 for(l=0; l<10; l++)
  {
          projects[l].identifier = 00000;
          projects[l].price = 0.00;
          strcpy(projects[l].customer.name,"----------");
          strcpy(projects[l].customer.surname,"----------");
          strcpy(projects[l].date, "0/0/0");
  }          
}          

struct meletes newp(struct meletes projects[10])
{
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                  if (projects[i].identifier == 00000)
                 {
                    scanf("Please enter the project's identifier %d\n",        &projects[i].identifier);
                    scanf("Name:%s\n", &projects[i].customer.name);
                    scanf("Surname:%s\n", &projects[i].customer.surname);
                    scanf("Give the date in dd/mm/yyyy! format :%c\n", &projects[i].date);
                    scanf("Price:&f\n", &projects[i].price);
                 }
             break;
        }                

}

struct meletes deletep(struct meletes projects[10])
{
       int j,id;
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            if (projects[j].identifier != 00000)     //Emfanizei oles tis meletes pou den ine diegrammenes
               {
               printf("%d\n", projects[j].identifier);
               }
        }

        scanf("\nPlease insert the identifier of the project u want to delete:%d", &id);

        for(j=0; j<10; j++)
        {                       
          projects[j].identifier = 00000;
          projects[j].price = 0.00;
          strcpy(projects[j].customer.name,"----------");
          strcpy(projects[j].customer.surname,"----------");
          strcpy(projects[j].date, "0/0/0");
        }

}

struct meletes list(struct meletes projects[10])
{
       int k;
        for(k=0; k<10; k++)
        {
                 if (projects[k].identifier != 00000); 
                    {
                    printf("         Project %d:", k);
                    printf("\nIdentifier:%d\n", projects[k].identifier);
                    printf("Name:%s\n", projects[k].customer.name);
                    printf("Surname:%s\n",projects[k].customer.surname);
                    printf("Date:%s\n", projects[k].date);
                    printf("Price:%d\n", projects[k].price);
                    }
        }

 }        `
```

Any ideas will be really appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. Please look this over and let us know what you learned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct 
{
        char name[10];
        char surname[10];
}fullname;

typedef struct 
{
        int identifier;
        fullname customer;
        char date[10+1]; /* need a NULL */
        float price;
}meletes;

void initialize(meletes *projects);
meletes *newp(meletes *projects);
void list(meletes *projects);
void deletep(meletes *projects);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int choice,k;
    meletes projects[10];
    meletes *retMeletes;

    initialize(projects);

    printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
    printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
    printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    while ((choice != 1) && (choice != 2) && (choice != 3) && (choice != 4))
    {

           printf("You have chosen a wrong function, please use numbers 1-4:\n\n");
           printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
           printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
           printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
           scanf("%d", &choice);
    }

    while (choice != 4)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                retMeletes = newp( projects);
            break;

            case 2:
                deletep(projects);
            break;

            case 3:
                list(projects);
            break;
        }

        printf("Main Menu\n ========\n");
        printf("Please choose a function from below:\n");
        printf("1.New Project\n2.Delete\n3.List\n4.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &choice);             
    }

    printf("Thank u.\n");

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void initialize(meletes *projects)
{
    int l;
    for(l=0; l<10; l++)
    {
        projects[l].identifier = 00000;
        projects[l].price = 0.00;
        strcpy(projects[l].customer.name,"----------");
        strcpy(projects[l].customer.surname,"----------");
        strcpy(projects[l].date, "00/00/0000");
    }          
}          

meletes *newp(meletes *projects)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (projects[i].identifier == 0)
        {
            printf("Please enter the project's identifier: ");
            scanf("%d", &projects[i].identifier);
            printf("Name: ");
            scanf("%s", &projects[i].customer.name);
            printf("Surname: ");
            scanf("%s", &projects[i].customer.surname);
            printf("Give the date in dd/mm/yyyy! format: ");
            memset( &projects[i].date, 0x00, sizeof( projects[i].date ));
            scanf("%s", &projects[i].date );
            printf("Price: ");
            scanf("%f", &projects[i].price);
            break;
        }
    }                
    return( &projects[i] );
}

void deletep(meletes *projects)
{
    int j,id;

    for (j=0; j<10; j++)
    {
        if (projects[j].identifier != 0)     //Emfanizei oles tis meletes pou den ine diegrammenes
        {
            printf("%d\n", projects[j].identifier);
        }
    }

    printf("\nPlease insert the identifier of the project u want to delete: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);

    projects[id-1].identifier = 0;
    projects[id-1].price = 0.00;
    strcpy(projects[id-1].customer.name,"----------");
    strcpy(projects[id-1].customer.surname,"----------");
    strcpy(projects[id-1].date, "0/0/0");

    return;
}

void list(meletes *projects)
{
    int k;

    for(k=0; k<10; k++)
    {
        if (projects[k].identifier != 00000); 
        {
            printf("         Project %d:", k);
            printf("\nIdentifier:%d\n", projects[k].identifier);
            printf("Name:%s\n", projects[k].customer.name);
            printf("Surname:%s\n",projects[k].customer.surname);
            printf("Date:%s\n", projects[k].date);
            printf("Price:%f\n", projects[k].price);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much man. Your help is greatly appreciated.

So starting off first thing i notice is typedef. It basically defines a variable to be equal to a variable type thus saving me the effort to write struct every time right?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes that is basically correct. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef If you find my example helpful please feel free to accept my answer. If you have other questions please ask.

Comment: Ok did that! I cant press the up arrow button though.
1 thing i really dont get are the 2 variables inside the main() function? i dont see any of those 2 being called anywhere? what is their purpose?

Comment: meletes *retMeletes; is used to hold the return value from the newp() function. The code doesn't use the return value of newp() but it could. You could also just make newp() not return anything if you don't need to know the details of the project added and then remove retMeletes. The other variables in main existed in your original source I believe.

Answer (score 2):

The following lines in `main` are declaring the functions, but do not *call* thyem

```
void initialize(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes newp(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes deletep(struct meletes projects[10]);
struct meletes list(struct meletes projects[10]);
```

You need to *call* the functions, like this:

```
initialize(projects);
newp(projects);
deletep(projects);
list(projects);
```

The last three seem to return a `meletes` structure as well, you need to declare an new variable of type `meletes` and use it as appropriate:

```
struct meletes proj = newp(projects);
// use proj as appropriate
```

On second look the functions `newp`, `deletep` and `list` *do not* return anything, which will casue problems if you go with the above suggested assignment.  You either need to return a project (and the assignment will be fine) or change their return type to `void` (and don't do the assignment).

Comment: Ok I ve corrected your first point and the functions are now called properly though not working properly :S

Working on other ones

Comment: Make sure your formatting specifiers in `scanf` and `printf` are correct (e.g. you have `%d` with a float `price` in `list()`

Comment: Ok corrected that one 2. The only working function so far is the "list" function. The initializing function and newproject functions are just giving me crap. When i choose "1" to enter a new project it just gives me a bunch of random numbers, I cant input anything. Any idea of whats causing that?

Comment: For the initializer: you are copying 11 characters into a 10 character space (10 dashes and one terminating `'\0'`), which will overwrite other memory, not belonging to those buffers.  Of the `newp()`: use `printf`+`scanf`, `scanf` does not do what you think it does (read the effect of the string parameters [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/))

Comment: If this is homework, you might want to add the "homework" tag.